# MySQL LIKE operator behaving like = operator

Tags: mysql, sql-like, wordpress

It seems MySQL's LIKE operator behaves like a = operator.

The following MySQL query returns the expected result (1 entry):

```
$meta_key = '_locality';
$meta_value = 'The Hague';
$post_ids = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare( 
  "
  SELECT      post_id
  FROM        $wpdb->postmeta
  WHERE       meta_key = %s
              AND meta_value LIKE %s
  ", 
  $meta_key, 
  $meta_value
) );
```

But the following, with only part of the original meta_value, returns an empty array:

```
$meta_key = '_locality';
$meta_value = 'The';
$post_ids = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare( 
  "
  SELECT      post_id
  FROM        $wpdb->postmeta
  WHERE       meta_key = %s
              AND meta_value LIKE %s
  ", 
  $meta_key, 
  $meta_value
) );
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You have no wildcards set. Try `$meta_value = 'The%';` instead.

Comment: Yes! Thanks a lot. (If you post it as an answer, I'll accept it.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read mysql pattern matching syntax carefully: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html . You lose '%' for LIKE matching:

```
$meta_key = '_locality';
$meta_value = '%The Hague%';
$post_ids = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare( 
  "
  SELECT      post_id
  FROM        $wpdb->postmeta
  WHERE       meta_key = %s
              AND meta_value LIKE %s
  ", 
  $meta_key, 
  $meta_value
) );
```